# Parameterize a path in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with recursive derivative formula and initial condition

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have in mind a path $\gamma:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ with some conditions, and I'm wondering if I can parameterize it nicely. I will denote $\gamma(t)$ by $\gamma_t$. Also, to avoid complex analysis, I will let $i=\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}0 & -1\\ 1 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ be the $\pi/2$ rotation matrix. Here are the conditions on $\gamma$:

1. $\gamma_0=(1,0)$.
2. $\gamma$ is infinitely differentiable with derivatives given by $\gamma^{n+1}=\mathbf{u}(i\gamma^n-\gamma^n)$ where $\mathbf{u}(\cdot)$ returns unit vector.

I strongly believe that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\gamma_t=\mathbf{0}$ and possibly there exists some $T$ for which $\gamma_t=\mathbf{0}$ whenever $t\geq T$. In this case, $2$ is violated for $t\geq T$. Anyway, I am most interested in parameterizing such a path if it unique.

Edit: On working with $2$ I have an easier condition:

$$\gamma^{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{i-1})\gamma^n$$

where $\mathbf{i-1}=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & -1\\ 1 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)-\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)=\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}-1 & -1\\ 1 & -1\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ which has determinant $2$.

Comment: Are condition 2. and $|\gamma^n|=1$ valid for every $t$ or only at $t=0$?

Comment: Valid for every $t$, but I believe at time $T$ every $\gamma^n$ will become $\mathbf{0}$, so the condition holds until then.

Comment: Mmm... and why do you think that?

Comment: In my opinion, because the speed is constant, they will never reach the zero.

Comment: $\gamma$ is always pointed inside the unit circle, so it's moving closer to $\mathbf{0}$. Since it has unit speed, I expect it will reach it, upon whence the formula for $\gamma^n$ yields $\mathbf{0}$ for all $n$

Comment: This is straight forward when you take the codomain to be $\Bbb C$. Your differential equation is just $\gamma^{(n)} = a\gamma^{(n-1)}$ for a certain constant $a$. If it holds for $n = 0$, it will hold for all higher $n$ as well. And the differential equation for $n = 0$ has a very well known solution.

Comment: Could you share a source? Or just say, what is the solution for $\gamma^{(0)}$?

Comment: The solution Paul is referring to is the exponential.